# HOWTO Programatically construct Google News Search URL so that I can open a new browser window/tab with it

Tags: google-search, google-search-api

In one of my apps I want to open a new window/tab for a "google news" query. Is there an official documentation where I can look up what all different google search parameters mean & what encoding I need to do for certain parameters like time-range. I got hold of some unofficial links like [this](http://www.blueglass.com/blog/google-search-url-parameters-query-string-anatomy/) but it is not exhaustive. I dont want to reverse engineer the sample queries that I fired on Google News page.

My goal is to just simply programatically construct the google search url & direct the user to it, I do not want to get just the JSON etc search result else I would have used the [Google News Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/newssearch/), which BTW is deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

`http://news.google.co.uk/news?q=appreciated`

You can also get an RSS feed:

`http://news.google.co.uk/news?q=appreciated&hl=en&prmd=imvns&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss`

Comment: Works for me in Chrome and using `curl`.